# Unable to read <p> text under <h3> using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an html code something like:

```
<h3> Some Heading </h3>
<p> Some String </p>
<p> more string </p>
<h3> Other heading</h3>
<p> some text </p>
```

I am trying to access `Some String`, `more string` and `some text`. With java, am trying to access like this:

```
List<WebElement> h3Tags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));

List<WebElement> para = null;

WebElement bagInfo = h3Tags.get(0);  //reads first h3
if(bagInfo.getText().contains("carry-on") || bagInfo.getText().contains("Carry-on")){
        para = AutoUtils.findElementsByTagName(bagInfo, "p");
        System.out.println(para.get(0).getText());  //Null pointer here 
}

bagInfo = h3Tags.get(1);
if(bagInfo.getText().contains("checked") || bagInfo.getText().contains("Checked")){
        para = AutoUtils.findElementsByTagName(bagInfo, "p");
        System.out.println(para.get(0).getText());  //Null pointer here too
}
```

Tried `xpath` like `"h3['/p']"` but still no luck. What is the best way to access those `<p>` strings?

Comment: With xpath //h3/following::p

Answer (score 2):

Try xpath `//h3/following-sibling::p` to match all 3 paragraphs

Also note that your XPath `h3['/p']` doesn't work as it means *return `h3` node which is DOM root node*. Predicate `['/p']` will always return True as non-empty string (`'/p'` in your case) is always True

Answer (score 0):

To access **Some String**, **more string** and **some text** you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

- To access the node with text as **Some String**

  ```
  By.xpath("//h3[normalize-space()='Some Heading']//following::p[1]")
  ```
- To access the node with text as **more string**

  ```
  By.xpath("//h3[normalize-space()='Some Heading']//following::p[2]")
  ```
- To access the node with text as **some text**

  ```
  By.xpath("//h3[normalize-space()='Other heading']//following::p[1]")
  ```
- Once you locate those elements you can use **`getAttribute("innerHTML")`** method to extract the text within the nodes.